# How to compute numerically the $H^{1/2}$ norm of a function

Tags: finite-element, elliptic-pde, l2-norm

I'm, in the context of FEM. Let's say I have a discrete function $g$ living on the boundary of my domain $D$. I need to compute **numerically** $||g||_{1/2,\partial D}$.

The definition I know is the following:
$$\iint_{\partial D \times \partial D} \frac{\vert g(x)-g(y) \vert^2}{\vert x -y \vert^2} d s_xd s_y$$

However, I've heard of people saying that this norm can be computed by multiplying the square of $g$ with with a factor of $h$. I can't find any reference about this, and any practical advice is very much appreciated.

Comment: I think you have to elaborate what these people may have meant because clearly a term to integrate and the same term but multiplied by $h$ are not the same.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Essentially, they were talking about a way to compute that norm in practice, but I wasn't able to grasp the details. What I am really interested is how that norm is computed in practice in FEM papers. I've seen it used in some FEM articles by they never write explicitely the definition.

Answer (score 6):

I think what you are referring to is $\|h^{-1/2}g\|_{0,\partial D}$. The point is that it can be though of as the 'discrete' $H^{1/2}$ norm.

It comes down to the so called 'inverse inequalities' where you divide by $h$ to estimate the derivative, by $h^2$ to estimate the second derivative and, by extension, $h^{1/2}$ to estimate the fractional 1/2 derivative. You can look up also 'mesh-dependent norms'.

For this particular norm, I've often defined $\|g\|_{1/2,\partial D}$ as $\inf_{f \in H^1(D), f|_{\partial D}=g} |f|_{1,D}$. This actually corresponds to solving a Poisson equation with the boundary condition $g$ and zero loading and evaluating the energy norm of the solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please elaborate a little more on why this can be thought as a discrete $H^{1/2}$ norm? Also a reference is perfect actually. What I am missing is why this the inequality is so sharp that one can use directly that $L^2$-scaled norm @knl

Comment: The inequality is not sharp. But usually you are interested in some asymptotic convergence rate with respect to $h$ and then it should be good enough. There isn't a single specific reference I know of. You need to go through a pile of research papers. E.g. many DG papers use these or similar norms.

Comment: One last thing: to compute that integral one has then to multiply, on each element $e \in \partial D$, the corresponding size of the element $h_e$ with the function, right? I mean, that $h$ is a $h(x)$, right?

Comment: Exactly. I usually reuse the determinant of the affine mapping because that scales as $h^2$ (edit: depending on the dimension!).